# Pipe list into purrr::map and use seq_along in .x

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, purrr

Often I generate lists of tibbles that I then wish to pipe forward into a `purrr::map` call. Quite often I want to add an identifier column to each tibble and then join them together. I am looking for a way to not have to generate intermediate variables that pollute my global environment just to be able to use seq_along to add the id column.

Load library:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Generate reprex:

```
reprex_list <- list(Aleena = structure(list(
  name = "Ratts Tyerell", height = 79L,
  mass = 15, hair_color = "none", skin_color = "grey, blue",
  eye_color = "unknown", birth_year = NA_real_, gender = "male",
  homeworld = "Aleen Minor", films = list("The Phantom Menace"),
  vehicles = list(character(0)), starships = list(character(0))
), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), Besalisk = structure(list(
  name = "Dexter Jettster", height = 198L, mass = 102, hair_color = "none",
  skin_color = "brown", eye_color = "yellow", birth_year = NA_real_,
  gender = "male", homeworld = "Ojom", films = list("Attack of the Clones"),
  vehicles = list(character(0)), starships = list(character(0))
), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), Cerean = structure(list(
  name = "Ki-Adi-Mundi", height = 198L, mass = 82, hair_color = "white",
  skin_color = "pale", eye_color = "yellow", birth_year = 92,
  gender = "male", homeworld = "Cerea", films = list(c(
    "Attack of the Clones",
    "The Phantom Menace", "Revenge of the Sith"
  )), vehicles = list(
    character(0)
  ), starships = list(character(0))
), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L)))
```

From here, what I am having to do is generate an intermediate variable in my global environment and start map again as follows:

```
species_id <- names(reprex_list) # don't want to have to break the pipe and add this to my blobal environment
map(.x = seq_along(reprex_list), .f = ~reprex_list[[.x]] %>%
  dplyr::mutate(species = species_id[[.x]])) %>%
  map(.f = ~ .x %>% mutate_all(as.character)) %>%
  purrr::reduce(full_join) %>%
  type_convert()
```

Foolishly, what I'd like instead is:

```
reprex_list %>% # Sometimes this is piped in from many previous lines of code so I don't want to have to assign this to a separate variable to be able to carry on.
  map(.x = seq_along(.), .f = ~ .[[.x]] %>% dplyr::mutate(species = names(.)[[.x]])) %>%
  map(.f = ~ .x %>% mutate_all(as.character)) %>%
  purrr::reduce(full_join) %>%
  type_convert()
```

But the latter doesn't work. Now obviously the extra hassle is minimal here but sometimes I will have already had multiple lines of code before I generate the intermediate list, which I then have to assign to a separate variable. And then start piping again, which I'm pretty sure could be done in one code chunk but I haven't found a way for that yet. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Does `dplyr::bind_rows(reprex_list, .id = "species") %>% tidyr::unnest(films)` get close to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `purrr::map_dfr` with the `.id` argument specified:

```
reprex_list %>% map_dfr(~mutate_all(., as.character), .id='species')
```

Or even better to add the species column and do nothing else:

```
reprex_list %>% map_dfr(identity, .id='species')
```

EDIT:

```
reprex_list %>% bind_rows(.id = "species")
```

is actually the best way to do this, as per comment above

Comment: It's close... It replaces the `purrr::reduce(full_join)` which would solve about ~90% of the use cases. The question is more around if it is possible to use `.x = seq_along()` downstream of a pipe?

Comment: You could use `imap` - I'll post a full answer later